# PHP How to track user's navigation path through a website

Tags: php, google-analytics, seo, analytics

So we plan to track a user's activity within our website which are in PHP.
What we want to know is track a unique session for a user from the time he first visits a page in our site, the pages he visited next, and visited last.

Some kind of tracking his footprint through our site.
We actually have identified 2 methods, one is using a custom code, and the other is analytics.js.

We find analytics.js too much for this (and my take more time to setup including time for our Internal Team to familiarize/learn the tool).
Considering what we need is just getting the timelogs of the user's session.

So we'll be going with a custom code added to each of the pages that need tracking. This script will do the follow:

- we will be pasting code snippets to pages that need tracking
- generate a unique session ID once he lands on any of the tracked pages
- records the activity on a database
- create an admin dashboard to visualize each of the user's activity, just a simple UI to showing the timelogs and pages visited

That's our plan so just wondering if the above is acceptable, or if there's any other easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance StackOverflow community!

Comment: Google Analytics does not track individual users (partly for privacy and mostly because once you have more then three or so users a day this results in a useless heap of disparate data points). In any case general reference questions are off-topic.

Comment: You are able to track individual users. You have to create a property inside analytics account, and configure the piece of javascript for your application you got from google. Inside analytics you are then able to sort/filter by specific user. Note that the visitor reference must not be traceable to a person. For example your not allowed to use email adres or ip. If you however to create a signuture from lets say browser information, then you will be using valid data that is not traceable to a person.

Comment: @PAlphen - Yes I am aware that we can track users and filter a specific user's data on GA, but what we need is a tool that can track the user's specific "trail" - so a data like "John Doe" has the following trail: Homepage --> Shop Page --> Product Detail Page --> Order Page --> Order Confirmation Page --> Contact Page. This is possible with analytics.js but like I said, it is just too much for it; so we decided to go with a custom PHP code, as described in my question. We are just interested if there is an easier way with the proposed custom PHP code I posted.

Comment: GA provides an API for getting data from analytics, this way you can build your own GUI to keep it simple. Via custom php code you simply write a record to your database. To gain the previous url you can use either sessions or $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'])